# Python выдаёт ответ не по программе

Tags: python

кто, поможет?

почему в этом моменте кода

```py
matr = [] #матрица и её заполнение нулями
t = [0 for i in range(10)]
for i in range(10):
    matr += [t]

p = [[5, 1], [3, 2], [7, 1], [5, 2], [7, 4], [6, 5], [6, 4], [7, 5], [2, 1], [5, 3]] 

for a in p:
    x, y = a
    print(x, y)#===========
    matr[x][y] = 1

for a in matr: print(a)#===========
```

выдаёт

```
5 1
3 2
7 1
5 2
7 4
6 5
6 4
7 5
2 1
5 3
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

хоть должен нарисовать матрицу

пробовал в debug режиме - питон всё делает на одной строке и дублирует значения

Comment: "p" это что такое? И matr? Матрица и нарисована, кстати.

Comment: @Эникейщик это масив: `[[5, 1], [3, 2], [7, 1], [5, 2], [7, 4], [6, 5], [6, 4], [7, 5], [2, 1], [5, 3]] `

Comment: @Эникейщик matr - матрица(которую он делает не по программному коду)

Comment: Почему вы решили что matr это правильная матрица?

Comment: `matr = []` — это абсолютно не похоже на матрицу, зато похоже на обычный список

Comment: @andreymal с чего ей быть неправильной(у меня всегда она работала)

Comment: @KvaksManplay с чего бы ей быть правильной, если прямо сейчас она у вас не работает?

Comment: @andreymal добавил всю нужную часть

Comment: `matr += [t]` — таким кодом вы добавляете список `t` десять раз в список `matr`, то есть у вас внутри `matr` находится **один и тот же** список десять раз. И любое значение `matr[x]` будет указывать на **один и тот же** список, поэтому и print выводит десять одинаковых списков (потому что это один и тот же список `t`)

Comment: @andreymal а как тогда по другому сделать генерацию матрицы(у меня до этого работало в 2 задачках)?

Comment: @KvaksManplay вместо списка t добавлять копию списка t

Comment: @andreymal как?

Comment: Ну уж ответ на вопрос «python копировать список» в интернете найти точно проблем не должно же быть... `matr += [t[:]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вроде рабочий код

```
matr = [[0 for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)] #матрица и её заполнение нулями

p = [[5, 1], [3, 2], [7, 1], [5, 2], [7, 4], [6, 5], [6, 4], [7, 5], [2, 1], [5, 3]] 

for a in p:
    x, y = a
    print(x, y)#===========
    matr[x][y] = 1

for a in matr: print(a)#===========
```

Comment: уточните, в графе нумерация координат может включать в себя 0? Или все же стоит уменьшать данные значения на 1

Answer (score 0):

Ты хотел нарисовать диагональ из единичек? или я не понял? Если да, то ты в переменные x и y кладешь не числа 1, 2,... А сами списки с двумя элементами. Проще говоря, используя цикл

```
for a in p:
    #Итерация
```

ты прогоняешь переменную a по списку p, при этом а принимает значение n-ого элемента, а не его индекс.
Но если я неправильно понял, то так и напиши.

Comment: он должен был нарисовать матрицу смежностей графа

Comment: массив p это номера вершин которые соприкасаются друг с другом

Comment: а почему ты используешь еще один список для генерации матрицы? Можно же генератором воспользоваться

Comment: побывал - не работало ```matr = [[0 for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]```

Comment: так ты используешь одну и ту же переменную i. это как во вложенном цикле ее использовать два раза.